# HTML table design issue

Tags: html, html-table

I´m generating a pdf to print the bill, but in Argentina we have an easy but tricky design which I cannot figure out how to do it! I need to make it with html tables.

[image: Design]

It is very simple, but I can´t do it and it´s driving me crazy!

I appreciate all the help.

HERE is my code:

```
<table border= "1" width="50%">
    <tr>
        <td  > Merge 1  </td>
        <td colspan="2" align="center">A</td>
        <td> Merge 2  </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Merge 1</td>
        <td colspan="2">Merge 2</td>

    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: What have you tried and what issues have you run in to?

Comment: We are not a code writing service. Try doing it yourself, and if you come across a specific problem, (Incorrect floating or something) then you can come here for help.

Comment: I posted the code, i need to merge the rows "merge 1 with merge 1" and "merge 2 with merge 2"

Comment: I made the mistake of asking a question in an "answer" - Gustavo said he is using TCPDF, and CSS was not working well with that library.

Comment: I suppose the tricky part is the center box with the 'B', but you can't do that only with a table, you need to use `<div>`s styled with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using PDF Forms? Then you can design the pdf as you want and just fill in the data you need at runtime